# how to use tailwind with bun

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, bun

I'm creating a react app using [bun.sh](https://bun.sh).

But I also use tailwindcss for styling and tailwind has no official solution for bun. How can use these two together?

I know bun is not ready for production but I'm still looking for a solution if its possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run a javascript file (or a package.json script or a bin file) with using
`bun run` followed by the library name.

In your case, first add the tailwindcss package to your project:
`bun add -d tailwindcss`

Then initialize tailwind css like this
`bun run tailwindcss init`

This should add the tailwind.config.js file to your project.

Answer (score 5):

To use Tailwind with bun, use the Tailwind CLI and import the processed .css file. Learn more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

or

```
bun tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
bun run tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Use that output.css in your main file and done!

Comment: in cra, it is compiled automatically, is that possible with bun without any effort?

Comment: @TayfunErbilen with a plugin, yes.

Answer (score 0):

use CLI instation methode using npx or npm  it

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation